# using bing maps in windows store app for an x86 or x64?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I'm developing a Windows Store App where I use the Bing Maps SDK. All is working OK. The only question I have is regarding the way how it should be confgure.

I 'm following this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846489.aspx
There they mention **"Reference Bing Maps SDK and Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package as"**:

1. Select PROJECT, then Add Reference from the main menu. (For a Visual C++ project, select PROJECT >yourProjectName Properties, then click Add Reference.)
2. In the Add Reference dialog, expand Windows, then select Extensions.
3. Check Bing Maps SDK for C#, C++, or Visual Basic and the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package and click OK.

I have done that choosing x64 and it's working OK.

My concern is at the moment to public the App. Due to this configuration, when the users want to download the App, should they have a computer with an x64 architecture?

Sorry, if this is a silly question. but I'm new in this ;-)

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may helps you-

1. Neutral, you will get a single package with builds that will run on any Windows 8 hardware.
2. If you select individual builds you will get a different package for each build type.
3. If you are building an app which requires a lot of memory and processing power and you have not tested it on ARM, you might want to consider selecting x86 and x64 specifically and not including ARM in your release.

for more reference check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2012/11/30/publishing-windows-8-app-to-the-windows-store-how-to.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info Arun. So, I guess I don't have any to worry about. Now, I select x86 since when choosing x64 the designer does't work.